# Finding an example of a function

Tags: real-analysis

1. Prove that there exists a differentiable function $f:(0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ such that $f(f'(x)) = x, \: \forall x>0.$
2. Prove that there is no differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f'(x)) = x, \: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$

I am trying to find the example of such a function.

Comment: For part 1, try functions of the form $a x^b$.

Answer (score 1):

We can simply look for a solution of form $ax^b$. Note that $f(f’(x)) = a(abx^{b-1})^b = a^{b+1}b^bx^{b^2-b}$. So we simply let $b$ be a solution of $b^2-b=1$, and then find an appropriate $a$ such that $a^{b+1}b^b=1$.

Comment: I think that there is not solution for some a,b

Comment: b=phi, the golden ratio, is a solution

Comment: Ooook sorry, you’re right